# How to open a file from a perl module

Tags: perl

I have a module called Conf.pm and it opens a file called conf.json.
conf.json relative path from conf.pm is ".../conf/conf.json";

But when I include Conf.pm in scripts that are in other folders the relative path changes and Conf.pm does not find conf.json.

How can I open conf.json from Conf.pm.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use the module `FindBin` which allows you to work 'relative to my location' in a module.

In your `.pm` add:

```
use FindBin;
my $home_path = $FindBin::RealBin; 
my $json_path = $home_path."/../conf/conf.json";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
use File::Basename;
my $dirname = dirname(__FILE__);
```

in order to get the path of the current script (i.e., conf.pm) and then add `../conf/conf.json` to it